# Не работает вывод через PDO

Tags: pdo, php

Вот код:

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'a9119841_blog';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host = '.$db_host.'; dbname = '.$db_name, $username, $password);
    echo "Connected to the ".$db_name;

 //Ошибка тут, внизу:
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM posts";
    $result = $db -> query($sql);

    foreach($result as $row){
        echo $row['id'];
    }
}
catch(PDOexception $e) {
    echo $e -> getMessage();
}
?>
```

Просмотрел и оф мануал, и сайты пошарил, но почему то не выводит ничего. Выводит ошибку:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

И заодно, что посоветуете для изучения PDO? Да и сам ПХП я на базовом знаю. Хочу за лето научиться немного. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Перед циклом необходимо проверять, что содержит $result, там может быть false

    if($result)
        foreach($result as $row)
            ...

А вообще лучше сразу смотрите в сторону PDO::prepare, в офф. мануале достаточно примеров работы с этими методами

Comment: Вот:

        $sql = 'SELECT id, title, text FROM posts'; 
        $sth = $db -> prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth -> execute();
        
        $row = $sth -> fetch();
        if($row) echo "OK!"; else echo "No!";


Выдает "No!"; @MDJHD

Comment: А в таблице posts точно существует хотя бы одна запись? Если использовать mysql или mysqli вместо PDO работает?

Comment: Обновил код. Посмотрите на ошибку

Comment: Судя по тому, что у вас выводится массив, у вас отрабатывает следующая строка:

    print_r($db->errorInfo());

Предполагаю, что `dsn` (строку с параметрами в конструкторе PDO) надо все-таки писать без пробелов.

Answer (score 2):

В этом коде две основных проблемы.

1. Как правильно заметил Etki в комментариях, параметры при подключении указаны неправильно. Никаких пробелов в DSN быть не должно.
2. Не выбран правильный режим информирования об ошибках.

Что происходило раньше?

- из-за неверного DSN оказывалась не выбранной БД.
- из-за того, что не выбрана БД, запрос выполнялся с ошибкой
- но из-за неверного режима отображения ошибок, она не выводилась.

Вот правильный код:

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'a9119841_blog';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$result = $db->query("SELECT id FROM posts");
foreach($result as $row){
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Здесь DSN написан правильно и задан единственно верный режим отображения ошибок, `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

Отдельно следует отметить, что `try catch` c выводом `getMessage()` писать не надо вообще никогда - РНР прекрасно справится с выводом ошибки сам.

> что посоветуете для изучения PDO?

[Как работать с PDO? Полное руководство.](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo)

Answer (score -1):

выведи ошибку и посмотри что тебе говорит sql сервер
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Обновил. Смотрите код новый:

Answer (score -1):

Ни увел, что где-то присутствует "fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)", а выводите ассоциативный массив.

UPD:
    Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

это означает что ошибок нет по идеи. либо что-то с драйвером pdo не то, и он попросту не видит ошибку. была подобная проблема, позже дам свой вариант вашего кода

UPD: делайте так. и никаких ошибок..

```
<?php

# конфигурации
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'project';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

# выполнение подключения
try { 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_host.";dbname=".$db_name, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    echo "Мы подключены к ".$db_name;
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    die('PDO->ERROR::'.$e->getMessage());
}

# подготавливаем запрос
    $stm = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table');
# выполняем
    $stm->execute();
# преобразуем в ассоциативный массив
    $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

# используем как душе угодно
    if($row) {
        echo 'Таблица есть! Значит можно вывести с нее данные в ассоциативном массиве.';
    } else {
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
    }
```

Comment: исправил. Смотрите код новый: